# Efficiently way to compute colocation in space

Tags: matlab, gis, motion-detection

Given a polyline `P = {(x1, y1), ..., (xn, yn)}` and another polyline `Q = {(x1, y1), ..., (xm, ym)}` (m not equal n, so polylines could have different length), **colocation in space** occurs when the trajectories of moving objects P and Q, have some positions in common (Point A, B and C as seen in [example figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSUuO.png))

The concept is quite simple and visual perspective easily identify where colocation happen.
Hardest part is how to realize an algorithm that efficiently compute colocation and return the x and y coords where colocation happens!! This algorithm will be developed in matlab so I have all necessary to rapidly work.

Best regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to look at the function [INTERSECTIONS](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11837) from the Matlab File Exchange. See also the corresponding entry in the [File Exchange Pick of the week](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2011/09/09/detect-curve-intersections-quickly-and-easily/)

[image]

Comment: Do you know about existance of colocation of time and space? That means intersection need to be find in a 3dimensional mode: latitude, longitude, time.